# Split text form textbox and discard into different strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a text box where i put the text somthing like below

**if text is `Man,shirt,:businessman,-girl`**

then the result on the is

```
string Keyword = Man;
string or =shirt;
string And =businessman;
string not =girl
```

**if text is `Man,shirt,button,:businessman,-girl,-smile`**

then the result on the is

```
  string Keyword = Man;
    string or =shirt,button;
    string And =businessman;
    string not =girl,smile;
```

i want split -

```
 ',' to or
 ':' to and 
 '-' to not
```

Can any one give a solution to this issue.

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: Its a simple textbox and a submit button. i want that time result on button click hope u understand my query.

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve. What you're trying to do with the result?

Comment: *Can any one give a solution to this issue?* yes we do. It will be better if you tell what you're trying to do with these strings? There will be a better way to do. Also post what you tried? Which part you're struck?

Comment: Actually i have a keyword database where per image keywords stored into database column.and i want to search it from the keywords with and , or ,not

Comment: i want to split ',' to or
 ':' to and 
 '-' to not from the text which i type into textbox and store into different strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
    string text = yourtextbox.Text;
    string[] keyword = text.Split(':');
    string[] manArr = keyword[0].Split(',');

    string man = manArr[0];
    string or = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < manArr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (manArr[i].Trim() != "")
            or += manArr[i] + ",";
    }
    or = or.TrimEnd(',');
    string []andArr = keyword[1].Split('-');
    string and = andArr[0];
    string not = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < andArr.Length; i++)
    {
        not += andArr[i] + ",";
    }
    not = not.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: another question @ Mairaj Ahmad don't mind if the text is - Man,-shirt,:businessman,-girl is it possible to get the same result when we change the order of texts ??

Comment: No we will not get the same result because you will have to follow a pattren and i wrote code for that specific pattren.